# how to upload and convert image in base64 without storing the image in php

Tags: php

I can upload the image and save it in any location, then I convert that image in base64. but how can we do that we convert image in base64 without saving it. any solution please?

Comment: Any upload is automatically saved into a temp folder. You could encode this one, then choose not to save it to a proper folder.

Comment: sorry sir but can you please give me a demo code

Answer (score 2):

```
$photoTmpPath = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
$data = file_get_contents($photoTmpPath);
$base64 = base64_encode($data);
```

and if you want to test:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $data;
exit;
```

Comment: Perfect. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Web Form which manages your Image upoad through $_POST. You could use this ..

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST)){
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
    $size = $_FILES['file']['size']; 
    $type = $_FILES['file']['type']; 
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

    if(isset($name)){ 
      if(!empty($name)){ 
          $target_path = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
             echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name'])." has been uploaded";

             $im = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['name']);
             $imdata = base64_encode($im);   
             var_dump($im);
             unlink($_FILES['file']['name']);
          }
        }else{ 
            echo 'Please choose a File'; 
        } 
    }
}
?> 
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="file"> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload"> 
</form>
```

Comment: sorry but I can't failed to implement this or understand you

Comment: How are you uploading the images?

Comment: <?php
  $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
  $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  if(isset($name)){

  if(!empty($name)){


  }else{

  echo 'Please choose a File';

  }

  }


?>



<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>

Comment: Ive updated my answer, try that and tell me what the result is or if you get nay errors

Comment: it shows me two things
first id C:\xampp\tmp\php4E82.tmp
second is Warning: file_get_contents(png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\php\uploading\base64\index.php on line 17

but at the end it shows  Base64 is data:image/tmp;base64,File uploaded

Comment: sir I am waiting for you if you are free so please try to solve my problem,

Comment: Remove the `basename` in `file_get_contents(basename($_FILES['file']['name']));` as it needs the full path to read the file. Same for unlink. And btw you don't need to move_uploaded_file(). You can work on the temporary file to base64_encode it.

Comment: <?php 
if(isset($_POST)){
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
    $size = $_FILES['file']['size']; 
    $type = $_FILES['file']['type']; 
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

    if(isset($name)){ 
        if(!empty($name)){ 
            $im = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            $imdata = base64_encode($im);   
            var_dump($im);
        }else{ 
            echo 'Please choose a File'; 
        } 
    }
}
?> 
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="file"> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload"> 
</form>

Comment: your second last code that is working. that I post above

Comment: Can you select best answer please :D